# Getter/Setter Variable not being called

Tags: apex, trigger, getter, setter

I wrote a getter/setter variable to populate a map when an opportunity is updated. For some reason the code inside the accountProductForecastMap method is not being ran. I have used this similar getter/setter framework before without issue.

Trigger Handler Code :

```
public with sharing class OpportunityTriggerHandler extends TriggerHandler {

    private static List<Opportunity> newList;
    private static List<Opportunity> oldList;
    private static Map<Id, Opportunity> newMap;
    private static Map<Id, Opportunity> oldMap;

    public OpportunityTriggerHandler() {
        super('OpportunityTriggerHandler');
        newList = (List<Opportunity>) Trigger.new;
        oldList = (List<Opportunity>) Trigger.old;
        newMap = (Map<Id, Opportunity>) Trigger.newMap;
        oldMap = (Map<Id, Opportunity>) Trigger.oldMap; 
    }

    /*************** Getter/Setter Variables ****************/

    private static Map<Id, List<Product_Forecast__c>> accountProductForecastMap{
        get{
            System.debug('In Product Forecast Getter');
            if (accountProductForecastMap == null) {

                Set<Id> relatedAccountIds = new Set<Id>();

                for (Opportunity opp : newList) {
                    if(opp.AccountId != null) {
                        relatedAccountIds.add(opp.AccountId);
                    }
                }

                List<Product_Forecast__c> productForecastList = [
                    SELECT Id, Account__r.Id, Forecast_End_Date__c,
                    Forecast_Start_Date__c, Product__c, Target_Quantity__c
                    FROM Product_Forecast__c
                    WHERE Account__r.Id 
                    IN :relatedAccountIds
                ];

                Map<Id, List<Product_Forecast__c>> accountProductForecastMap = new Map<Id, List<Product_Forecast__c>>();

                for (Product_Forecast__c productForecast : productForecastList) {

                    if(accountProductForecastMap.containsKey(productForecast.Account__r.Id)) {
                        //add product forecast to list of values
                        accountProductForecastMap.get(productForecast.Account__r.Id).add(productForecast);

                    } else {
                        // add account id as key, and product forecast to list of values
                        accountProductForecastMap.put(productForecast.Account__r.Id, new List<Product_Forecast__c>{productForecast});
                    }
                }
            }
            System.debug('Product Forecast Map: ' + accountProductForecastMap);
            return accountProductForecastMap;

        } set;
    }
}
```

Trigger Code :

```
trigger OpportunityTrigger on Opportunity (before insert, 
                                           before update, 
                                           before delete, 
                                           after insert, 
                                           after update, 
                                           after delete, 
                                           after undelete) {

    new OpportunityTriggerHandler().run();

}
```

Comment: Welcome to SFSE! Please take a moment to read [How to Ask](/help/how-to-ask) and [take the tour](/tour). Including a [Minimal, *Complete* and Reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) would be helpful.

Comment: Welcome to SFSE.  Please take a moment to read [ask] and take the [tour]. Please [edit] your post to include the trigger code as well.

Comment: You need something to call the getter. They don't automatically run. Further, be careful of [name shadowing](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_name_shadowing.htm). Declaring a separate variable in the getter won't update the property defined in the class.

Comment: per sfdcfox, this line is using name shadowing `Map<Id, List<Product_Forecast__c>> accountProductForecastMap = new Map<Id, List<Product_Forecast__c>>();`. Don't redeclare the variable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You fell into a common error in getters (I make 'em myself)

The variable you want to return is declared here

```
private static Map<Id, List<Product_Forecast__c>> accountProductForecastMap{
    get{
       ...

    } set;
}
```

but inside the getter, you redeclare it:

```
Map<Id, List<Product_Forecast__c>> accountProductForecastMap = 
       new Map<Id, List<Product_Forecast__c>>();
```

so, all of the code from then on is modifying a local variable and NOT the variable defined with the getter

Simply change the errant line to:

```
accountProductForecastMap = new Map<Id, List<Product_Forecast__c>>();
```

and you'll get past your issue.

Comment: Thank you! Its working like a charm now (:

Comment: great - community convention is to accept the answer so others who encounter this issue will know there was a solution. Use the check mark by the answer